# JavaFX - IText - Open PDF when created

Tags: java, pdf, javafx, pdf-generation, itext

I have created this method to make a PDF using the IText libary.

```
   private void pdfluggage()
        throws Exception {
    try {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/fys", "fys", "Welkom01");
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM luggage ORDER BY luggage_id DESC LIMIT 1");
        Document document = new Document();
        String outputFile = "luggageform.pdf";

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(outputFile));

    //PdfDestination pdfDest = new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.XYZ, 0, 842, 1f);
    //writer.setOpenAction(PdfAction.gotoLocalPage(1, pdfDest, writer));


        //writer.setOpenAction(new PdfAction(PdfAction.PRINTDIALOG));

        document.open();

        Paragraph Paragraph1 = new Paragraph();
        Image image = Image.getInstance("file:Image/Corendon-Logo.jpg");
        Image image2 = Image.getInstance("file:Image/footer.png");
        image.scalePercent(55f);
        image2.scalePercent(35f);
        image2.setAbsolutePosition(0f, 0f);
        Paragraph1.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        Font font1 = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 25, Font.BOLD | Font.UNDERLINE);
        Font font2 = new Font(Font.FontFamily.COURIER, 15, Font.UNDERLINE);
        Font font3 = new Font(Font.FontFamily.COURIER, 15);

        Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Added luggage form", font1);

        Paragraph1.add(chunk);

        document.add(image);
        document.add(new Phrase("\n"));
        document.add(new Phrase("\n"));
        document.add(new Phrase("\n"));
        document.add(Paragraph1);
        document.add(new Phrase("\n"));
        document.add(new Phrase("\n"));
        document.add(new Phrase("\n"));
        document.add(new Phrase("\n"));
        while (rs.next()) {

            document.add(new Chunk("Luggage status: ", font3));
            Chunk chunk2 = new Chunk((rs.getString("status")));
            chunk2.setFont(font2);
            document.add(chunk2);
            document.add(new Phrase("\n"));
            document.add(new Chunk("Brand name: ", font3));
            Chunk chunk3 = new Chunk((rs.getString("brand_name")));
            chunk3.setFont(font2);
            document.add(chunk3);
            document.add(new Phrase("\n"));
            document.add(new Chunk("Luggage color: ", font3));
            Chunk chunk4 = new Chunk((rs.getString("color")));
            chunk4.setFont(font2);
            document.add(chunk4);
            document.add(new Phrase("\n"));
            document.add(new Chunk("Luggage type: ", font3));
            Chunk chunk5 = new Chunk((rs.getString("luggage_type")));
            chunk5.setFont(font2);
            document.add(chunk5);
            document.add(new Phrase("\n"));
            document.add(new Chunk("Number of wheels: ", font3));
            Chunk chunk6 = new Chunk((rs.getString("number_of_wheels")));
            chunk6.setFont(font2);
            document.add(chunk6);
            document.add(new Phrase("\n"));
            document.add(new Chunk("Weight category: ", font3));
            Chunk chunk7 = new Chunk((rs.getString("weight_category")));
            chunk7.setFont(font2);
            document.add(chunk7);
            document.add(new Phrase("\n"));
            document.add(new Chunk("Flight number: ", font3));
            Chunk chunk8 = new Chunk((rs.getString("flight_number")));
            chunk8.setFont(font2);
            document.add(chunk8);
            document.add(new Phrase("\n"));
            document.add(new Chunk("Comments: ", font3));
            Chunk chunk9 = new Chunk((rs.getString("comments")));
            chunk9.setFont(font2);
            document.add(chunk9);
            document.add(new Phrase("\n"));
            document.add(new Chunk("Current location: ", font3));
            Chunk chunk10 = new Chunk((rs.getString("current_location")));
            chunk10.setFont(font2);
            document.add(chunk10);
            document.add(new Phrase("\n"));

        }
        document.add(image2);



        document.close();

        rs.close();
        statement.close();
        connection.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException | DocumentException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TestPDF.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

When pressed on a button "Print PDF" this method should be executed. The only thing that I cannot seem to get working is to open the PDF file automatically when created using the button. Could anyone help me to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

To open it in the platform's default PDF viewer, you can do:

```
HostServices hostServices = ... ;
File file = new File(outputFile);
String url = file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm();
hostServices.showDocument(url);
```

Getting the host services instance is a bit of a pain: you need to call `getHostServices()` on the `Application` instance. Obviously, you can only do this in your `start()` or `init()` method, so you will most likely need to do that there and then pass that instance to the controller where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I developed a demo application for PDFs some time ago, and this was my handler method:

```
protected void handleFire() {
    try {
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(getFile());
    } catch (IOException | IllegalArgumentException | NullPointerException e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, String.format("Could not open file. %s", e.getMessage()));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's probably best to avoid mixing JavaFX API and AWT API if you can, though, no?

Answer (score 0):

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(filename));
```